# Design solutions for fragments and asynchronous processing in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns, asynchronous

I struggled with some issues about design complex tasks with fragments
use. Fragments and asynchronous approach are quite new for me, so I think it will be better to describe my app.

**Application**
App works with GitHub API and has two screens: list of repositories and details about selected one. For retrieving data from json I use Retrofit and store it in SQLite. **Little remark** As I understood Retrofit can be used asynchronously but in case of additional work with DB it is better to use asynchronous approach  for operations under DB also. In my case I'm checking internet connection: in case of absence I load data from DB. Otherwise I upgrade DB and then use it. Now I want to add fragments for different screen density support( usual master - detail workflow).

**And my questions are**

Where is the better place to run async tasks? Is it a right solution to make it in activity and then pass result to fragments?

What is the better solution for asynchronous processing? As I understood from my search about that, AsyncTask is deprecated but the easiest solution.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is a pain in the rear. Many beginners still seem to use it, but imho it's not worth learning it. Sooner or later you'll be bugged out by it because AsyncTask is error prone, has lots of caveats and tons of boilerplate code.

Retrofit does make it's calls asynchronously automatically, so you've got that covered already. Retrofit also plays very nice with [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) which is I guess considered *the* way of doing asynchronous things on Android these days. 
RxJava has a steeper learning curve initially than other patterns, but it's worth learning. If you got your database stuff working already, it won't be much work making ti asynchronous with Rx.

As for

> Is it a right solution to make it in activity and then pass result to
>   fragments?

If you don't follow an [MVP](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/) design approach, which is okay, in my opinion it's absolutely okay to do 'business logic' stuff in the Fragment and not let the Fragment call the Activity, then let the Activity get back to the Fragment. Whichever is easier for you and suits your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your background thread anywhere, but make sure it is cancelled if the class is garbage collected, and don't keep references (Context, callbacks) in your thread.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   private static interface OnDownloadThreadCompleteListener {
      public void onDone(String data);
   }

   private static class DownloaderThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

      private OnDownloadThreadCompleteListener mListener;      

      public DownloaderThread(OnDownloadThreadCompleteListener listener) {
         mListener = listener;
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInbackground(Void... args) {
         // Do your network request here
         return result;
      }

      @Override
      public void onPostExecute(String data) {
          if (mListener != null && !isCancelled()) {
             mListener.onDone(data);
          }

          mListener = null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled() {
         mListener = null;
      }
   }

   private DownloaderThread mThread;
   private OnDownloadThreadCompleteListener mListener;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      super.onCreate(bundle);

      mListener = new OnDownloadThreadCompleteListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDone(String data) {
            Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_git");

            fragment.show(data);
         }
      }

      mThread = new DownloaderThread(mListener);

      findViewById(R.id.btn_download).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            mThread.execute(null, null, null);
         }
      }
   }    

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if (mThread != null) {
         mThread.cancel(true);
      }

      mThread = null;
      mListener = null
   }

}
```